# Django Dynamic form

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I'm making Django web application and I don't know how to resolve this problem. I will be very grateful for your help.
I have my forms.py

```
CHOICES =(
    ("1", "sys_1"),
    ("2", "sys_2"),
    ("3", "sys_3"),
    ("4", "sys_4"),
)
#and so on, lots of elements

Class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
  text = forms.CharField()
  list = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CHOICES,widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

I want to achieve that if the user writes something in the text charfield the list should change the content of choice dynamically based on what was typed. Also, the list must remember marked checkboxes. Example(step list):

```
1. user inputs something in the char field
2. the list is changing
3. user marks some checkboxes
4. user deletes content in the char field 
5. the list is changing and displaying all elements but remember marked 
  checkboxes
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `forms.MultipleChoiceField()` to get objects of database and then serve them in `index.html` with a special key, then filter options by javascript like this:

At first create the models for author.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

specify the selection form and options with a query of database.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from . import models

CHOICES =[]

def choice():
    key = 0
    query = models.Author.objects.all()
    for obj in query:
        CHOICES.append((key, obj))
        key += 1
    return CHOICES

class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    author = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=choice(),
                                       initial='',
                                       required=False,
                                       widget=forms.Select(attrs={'id': 'selection'}))
```

send your form to the `index.html` file.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import forms

def home(request):
    form = forms.ExampleForm
    return render(request, 'base.html', {'form': form})
```

At the end use `{{ form }}` in index.html and specify an `oninput` event to search by every new letter in input box.
Define a function in the script tag and search in the select options one by one with `includes()` method.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    <style>

    </style>

    </head>

    <body>

          <input type="text" oninput="myFunction(this.value)">

          {{form}}
          
    
    <script>

        function myFunction(value) {
            var x = document.getElementById("selection");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                text = x.options[i].text;
                if (text.includes(value) === false) {
                    x.remove(i);
                }
            }
            
          }

    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

also i used `remove()` method in `selectionObj.remove(indexNumber)` structure to every option what should delete.